# Integrate $\int\dfrac{1}{e^{2/y}}dy$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, indefinite-integrals

> $$\int\dfrac{1}{e^\frac{2}{y}}dy$$

I'm trying to integrate $\frac{dy}{dt}=e^{2/y}$. I've separated the equation to $\frac{1}{e^{2/y}}dy=dt$ so that I can integrate each side with respect to the corresponding variables. Computing the integral of $dt$ is trivial but I'm confused on how to compute the integral of $\frac{1}{e^{2/y}}dy$.

Comment: I have not tried, but maybe posing $z=-1/y$ could help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:)** This makes the integral simpler, with substitution $y=-\dfrac2u$ we have $dy=\dfrac{2}{u^2}$ and 
$$\int\dfrac{1}{e^\frac{2}{y}}dy=2\int\dfrac{e^u}{u^2}du$$

---

**Edit:**
\begin{align}
\int\dfrac{1}{e^\frac{2}{y}}dy
&= \int1-\dfrac{2}{y}+\dfrac{2^2}{2!}\dfrac{1}{y^2}-\dfrac{2^3}{3!}\dfrac{1}{y^3}+\cdots dy \\
&= y-2\ln y-\dfrac{2^2}{2!}\dfrac{1}{y}+\dfrac{2^2}{3!}\dfrac{1}{y^2}+\cdots
\end{align}

Comment: I tried this, too, but had no luck after the first pass in integration by parts.  You get something known to have no closed form.  Any ideas?

Comment: What do Wolfram say?

Comment: Nothing.  No can do.

Comment: @Randall Is my edit useful!

Comment: Well, I was searching for a closed form antiderivative, not a series rep.  I don't know that the OP needs.

Comment: @Randall See my answer in regards to the closed form…

Comment: @Randall So sorry. I thought you are the OP.

Comment: @MyGlasses  ha, no, just a guy who was really bothered by this integral.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this function has no elementary antiderivative:

$$\int e^{-2/y}\,dy=2\,\Gamma\left( -1,\frac2y\right)+C$$

where $\Gamma(s,x)$ is the [upper incomplete gamma function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function).

I arrived at this just by using [integral-calculator.com](https://www.integral-calculator.com).

(After @MyGlasses’s edit, I think his/hers is preferable. Nice trick, by the way!)

Answer (score 0):

Considering $$I=\int e^{-2/y}\,dy$$ integrate by parts $$u'=dy\implies u=y$$ $$v=e^{-2/y}\implies v'=\frac{2 e^{-2/y}}{y^2}\,dy$$ making 
$$I=y\,e^{-2/y}-2\int \frac{ e^{-2/y}}{y}\,dy=y \,e^{-2/y} +2\, \text{Ei}\left(-\frac{2}{y}\right)$$ where appears the exponential integral function.

This is just another represnation of what Chase Ryan Taylor gave in his/her answer.